# SQL VSS returns complete block size of the ldf files

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL VSS Writer to take backups of SQL Databases. What I actually do is take backups of files in form of mdf and ldf files by creating snapshots and taking backup of that snapshot. 
The issue which I came across is while taking Differential backup of ldf and mdf files, where for ldf file I was unable to get the changed blocks using "partial_files" method in vss. So suppose I have ldf file of size 10GB and only 100 changed rows which constitutes to 1 GB of data, VSS still returns complete block size of the ldf files. This leads us to scan complete file to check actual changed blocks which in turn increases backup time. Can you please let me know if you have faced this issue and how you solved?
Also, can you please suggest if I can switch to VDI type of backups or is VDI deprecated?

Comment: Taking snapshots of MDF/LDF files you are not getting true and proper backups. Why aren't you taking traditional backups of the database and the log? Please read [this](https://www.dcac.com/syndication/why-arent-san-snapshots-a-good-backup-solution-for-sql-server), [this](https://searchdatabackup.techtarget.com/feature/Using-snapshot-backups-to-replace-your-traditional-data-backup-system), and [this](https://www.itprotoday.com/should-i-be-using-san-snapshots-backup-solution) in full. Also see [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/151929/1186)...

Comment: ...and [this post](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/) about why copies of MDF/LDF files are not reliable backups.

Comment: In addition to the great stuff Aaron posted, VSS for Windows calls to the SQLWriter VSS interface which in turn executes VDI. So if you're using VSS correctly, it should already be calling in to SQLWriter and doing this. If you're just taking a Host or such based VSS snapshot which isn't calling into the actual Guest and invoking SQLWriter then you aren't even getting good snapshots.

Comment: Thanks a ton @AaronBertrand. I was using SQLWriter in my VSS snapshot backup method, but I was unaware of thing that it internally implements VDI. For transaction log backups, Yes I am using VDI interface implementation directly but for snapshot backups I was consuming VSS services. I will go through the links you posted which will surely help me and Can I get back to you if I have any more questions?

Comment: Thanks @SeanGallardy, I am using VSS writer to get snapshots but was unaware of fact that it uses VDI too. But the problem I was facing is when I don't take log backups, which keeps my log file to grow until space gets full. I was making mistake here actually, the number of differential backups I was taking are much more as compared to logs. If i increase log backups, i think my log file will not grow much. Please suggest if my understanding is correct?

Comment: If you aren't taking log backups, then the next one you do take will be all of the changes since the last one. so yes, more frequent log backups should result in smaller amounts of log backed up each time (the net changes since the last).

Comment: Thank you so much @SeanGallardy for clarification.